# Isomorphic of (N,+)?

Tags: linear-algebra

Does a binary operation * exist such that (N;+) and (Z;*) are isomorphic?
N : set of natural numbers, Z : set of integers and + is the addition operation. 
If yes, please give me an isomorphism function?

Answer (score 11):

Whenever you have two sets that are in bijection you can "transport" an operation, or any other algebraic structure, from one to the other. Namely, if $A$ is set endowed with an operation $+$ and $f:A\rightarrow B$ is a bijection of sets, you can define an operation $\ast$ on $B$ simply as
$$
b\ast b^\prime=f(a+a^\prime)
$$
where $a$ and $a^\prime$ are the unique elements in $A$ such that $f(a)=b$ and $f(a^\prime)=b^\prime$. Then $(B,\ast)$ is isomoprphic to $(A,+)$ by construction.

This can be applied to the question's case since there are surely bijections ${\Bbb N}\rightarrow{\Bbb Z}$. The problem is that the operations on $\Bbb Z$ that you construct in this way are very artificial and quite uninteresting.

Comment: Thanks, Andrea Mori for your answer but I can’t understand your explanation. I am confused.
My answer to this question is the function f(x) = x on (z , +). Is it correct? @andrea_mori

Comment: @mohammadasghari, the function $f:\Bbb{N}\rightarrow\Bbb{Z}$ given by $f(n)=n$ (i.e. the natural inclusion) is not a bijection. As a matter of fact, $\Bbb{Z}$ with addition is a group, while $\Bbb{N}$ is not.